# Seting up a minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting

I'm trying to setup a minecraft server:
server is on ubuntu comp, client on windows comp.

1) On my.public.ip.adress I can't play:
java.net.connectException: connection refused: no further information:80.80.80.80:25565

2) On 192.168.1.40(similar server's IP) it works, can play on LAN

---

So problem must be port forwarding:

3) tried the 25565 but also tried with another one.

4) on router i've set: 
NAT/virtualServers/add ----> 25565,25565,TCP/UDP,25565,25565,192.168.1.40
also 
NAT/Port Triggering ----> 25565,25565,TPC/UDP,25565,25565.

5) at canyouseeme.org it CAN see my service at 80.80.80.80:25565, it's visible.

6) at server's config file set: online mode:true/false both don't work

7) server's logs don't show any attempt of connection, problem must be on the router side.

halp! U_U

EDIT: window's firewall desactivated. still don't work

Comment: Is the server on your local network? Many routers don't allow local loop back. Is 80.80.80.80 really your IP address?

Comment: @TZHX I think it's just a mask.

Comment: 80.80.80.80 is my public IP, not THAT one but never say yor IP :P
server is on my local network.
If many servers don't allow local loopback I can't test it :(

Comment: Test it from a different connection. Connect to your server from your own network on a local IP address (usually 192.168.X.X). Other people connect using external IP. It's the router that stops local loop back (for valid reasons), not the server.

Comment: I'm flagging this question as off-topic because it appears to be a general networking problem, not one specific to games.

Answer (score 3):

Routers, as a general rule, do not allow local loop-back of connections, or *martian packets* as they are sometimes known. This is for valid network security reasons and the number of routers that make this optional are in the minority, and even if yours is one of them enabling it just to play a game is something I would strongly recommend against.

Connect to your server from the local network IP address (typically along the lines of `192.168.X.X`). Have your friends connect using the public IP address.

Comment: You might be right, @TZHX also suggested it and found same case on another forum. I'll need to wait some days to test it :D

Comment: @Javier Yeh, that TZHX seems to know what he's talking about.

Answer (score 0):

It could be your ISP (Internet Service Provider). Sometimes your ISP will block certain ports for some reason or another. A very common one the Minecraft port (25565). If this is your problem then you need to contact your ISP and see if you can get that port unblocked for you.

If that's not the case then it could be a combination of things. One, being your ISP blocking ports, and another such as the IP you are using. The 192.168.x.x IPs are generally internal IPs that your computer posses. The reason why when other people have this problem and only they can play is because they are connecting to their internal IP.

Also, make sure in your `server.properties` file that you leave the sever ip section blank. That also maybe the case in your situation.

Comment: server.properties/server ip now blank.
Tried port 7777, again: working on LAN, not working thru public IP
Must be the router's config 100% sure

Comment: Or your ISP, thats usually the case

Comment: If you really need to, use port 80 or 443 (HTTP/HTTPS). Those are almost never blocked XD. Other ports you can use are 21 (FTP), 22 (SSH/SFTP).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're trying to connect locally with your external IP address: it will never work **on some networks**.

Comment: If you use your external IP, it will still work, you just have to set it up properly.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "setup properly" ?

Comment: Port forwarding, obviously.  I'm disputing that it will never work; actually it will *always* work, once you do it right.  All it takes is some proper NAT knowledge.

Comment: For me, even with correct portforwarding, that won't work **locally**. My IP is redirected to the panel of my box.

Comment: Which means it's not correct port forwarding.  An external IP is exactly that; it will leave your network, and enter again just like other data.  For ANY external data to work, that has to be set up properly.

Comment: I will consider my portforwarding correct considering other networks' pc can correctly use my IP. It may be something particular with my router tho.

Comment: If it meets your needs, then it is correct.  But your statement that it will never work is completely untrue.  It will work, and rather easily, at that.